# Calling angular $broadcast from $http.success()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, broadcast, angular-schema-form

I have not be able to come up with a reasonable answer as to why I can't call $broadcast from within the $http.success() method. There are no errors and the $broadcast works outside of teh $http.success(). The listener is on a modified version of angular-schema-form-upload, [found here](https://github.com/jonathanread/angular-schema-form-nwp-file-upload)

Here is a simplified version.  How to i trigger the listener from within the success method of $http?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).factory('projects',['$http', '$rootScope',function($http, $rootScope){
  var service = {items:[], create: function(project){
    return $http.post('/myrails/api/project', project).success(function(data){
      service.items.push(data);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('schemaFormFileUploadSubmit', {project_id: data.id});//this never works
    });
  }};
  return service;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? (the success function does not exist anymore)  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: the success function works fine, if i put console.log('success works') within that method i see it in my console. angular v. 1.5.9

Comment: the $rootScope is not declared in the function is that a typo too?

Comment: looks like it is. I am trying to be sensitive here, so sorry about the issues. $rootScope is passed into the factory function.

Comment: Have you tried `then` in stead of `success`?

Comment: changing the service to use $http.then() instead of $http.success() causes and number of different issues and will require and restructure of how the create function is used, so this approach will not work.  I can't fathom why it is so difficult to $broadcast or $emit from within the success function. I also tried the $timeout and $apply with no success. grr

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Seems to work, unless I'm misunderstanding: http://plnkr.co/edit/4kbTudoM6eKdjLy3MSJw?p=preview

Comment: The listener for 'schemaFormFileUploadSubmit' never fires.

Comment: It the example I posted? It does for me.

Comment: Thank everyone for the input i have moved on to another solution and this is no longer a current issue, i dropped using angular schema-form.